# How can I interrupt the multithread pool to call a short function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

In my python script I call a function many times with different input parameters. For this I used multi-threading with `pool.apply_async` and call this many times inside a for. However, I want to check how many output files have been created so far as an indicator for progress. It seems that once the processes are running I cannot start this external function any time.

How can I interrupt and ask "hello, let's check the number of files with `FileCount()`?

Here is my code:

```
def FileCount(path):
  Path = os.getenv("HOME") + "/hbar_gshfs/" + path
  list_dir = []
  list_dir = os.listdir(Path)
  count = 0
  for file in list_dir:
    if file.endswith('.root'):
       count += 1
return count

main()    
  if args.run:
    mkdir_p(args.outdir)
    pool=Pool(10)
    for n in reversed(qnumbers):
        for pos in positions:
            for temp in temperatures:
                for fmap in BFieldmap:
                    for fseek in fieldSeek:
                        for lH, uH in zip(lowerHysteresis,upperHysteresis):
                            if BFieldmap.index(fmap) !=positions.index(pos):
                                continue

                            pool.apply_async(g4Run,args=(paramToOutputName(args.macrodir,temp, n, pos, fmap, fseek, lH, uH),))
    pool.close();
    pool.join();
```

I say thanks a lot for every input on that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Your `FileCount` function returns the number of files *created*, but not completely finished and filled with data (assuming `g4Run` creates one file in the beggining and then goes on to fill it with data). But it should be enough for a simple  progress indicator.

Otherwise you can use [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value). Pass it to every `g4Run` as an additional argument, and have `g4Run` increase it by one after it has finished doing its work.

To call your `FileCount` at fixed intervals, you can make use of the [`Pool.map_async`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async) call. For that transform your cycle into a generator:

```
def generate_params():
    for n in reversed(qnumbers):
        for pos in positions:
            for temp in temperatures:
                for fmap in BFieldmap:
                    for fseek in fieldSeek:
                        for lH, uH in zip(lowerHysteresis,upperHysteresis):
                            if BFieldmap.index(fmap) !=positions.index(pos):
                                continue

                            yield paramToOutputName(args.macrodir,temp, n, pos, fmap, fseek, lH, uH)

async_result = pool.map_async(g4Run, generate_params())

pool.close()
while not async_result.ready():
    async_result.wait(1) # Wait 1 second
    # Call FileCount here and output progress
pool.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. But unfortunately the code isn't running g4Run at all. But I am a quiet newbie inside Python.

Comment: Sorry, it's working perfectly now, exactly as you suggested in the code. The good thing at my simulation is, that the files are created after finishing the data, so it's a very good progress equivalent. But I am not sure if I understand your code completely. I believe to know that map_async(...) is automatically iterate the generator and start the threads with this iterated arguments. But what is exactly async_result.wait() doing. Is it waiting 1 second without blocking any process? And async_result.ready() is False until the last thread is completed? Thanks again. Best,

Comment: @HiggsBoson `pool` contains several threads (or are they processes? I believe Python doesn't provide `threading.Pool`, only `multiprocessing.Pool`) already created. Yes, `map_async` takes a value from the iterable (which is generator in this case) executes the function with this value on a free process from the `pool`. When some process in the pool finishes processing its value, `map_async` takes another value from the iterable and sends to it and so on until there are no more values in the iterable.

Comment: @HiggsBoson For `ready` and `wait` see the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult Basically, you are correct. `ready` tests if all the values from the iterable have been processed, and `wait` returns either after all the values have been processed or after the timeout has run out. IThose functions don't block execution of the processes. You can also pass shorter durations to wait if needed, e.g. `async_result.wait(0.1)` to wait 100 ms.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much, now I see. I clicked on the up Arrow, hope it's now accepted. If not please let me know. So thanks again for the time and nice greetings from CERN!